# Infinite scroll breaks grid

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a Wordpress/WooCommerce shop and I want to add Infinite Scroll to the product-view. For this purpose I use a infinite scroll plugin (by 61extensions).

We build the product grid using nth-child selector to select every first element in a row and clear it. However it seems like the plug-in outputs a div#infscr-loading in the middle of the product-items and so the grid breaks after the next page is loaded (see attached screenshot).

The website can be seen live here: http://d66.240.myftpupload.com/product-category/designers/ted-muehling/

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thank you so much for taking the time reading my question :).

Comment: Can you show your CSS? Have you considered using `:nth-of-type` instead of `:nth-child`?

Comment: :nth-of-type worked perfect. Thanks man :)

Comment: Cool. I'll make it an answer so that you can close this question out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`:nth-of-type`](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/nth-typen-css-selector/) instead so that the CSS for the columns won't be applied to the loader div.